# How do I call  glVertexPointer in Java?

Tags: c++, opengl, java, lwjgl, porting

I'm trying to convert the following code to Java:

```
glVertexPointer( 3, GL_FLOAT, 0, &(mesh.m_PositionBuffer[0]) );
```

Where `mesh::mPositionBuffer` is `std::vector<glm::vec3>`;

How would I make a similar call to `glVertexPointer` with a first index to the position buffer?

Comment: Which Java OpenGL API are you using?

Comment: I'm using LWJGL

Comment: Am I taking crazy pills or is that code C++? EDIT: Oh. `Porting` tag.

Answer (score 3):

You should look at the [overload set in the documentation](http://www.lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/opengl/GL11.html). Probably the candidate you're interested in would be the [glVertexPointer overload](http://www.lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/opengl/GL11.html#glVertexPointer%28int,%20int,%20java.nio.FloatBuffer%29) that takes a [FloatBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/FloatBuffer.html), which you'd fill with the components of the mesh's position vertices.